# Subtracting values based on date SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data that looks like this but with many more index names and index values

```
dt                     indx_nm      indx_val
2013-08-13 00:00:00.000 ABQI        1571.93
2013-08-12 00:00:00.000 ABQI        1568.55
2013-08-09 00:00:00.000 ABQI        1566.1
2013-08-08 00:00:00.000 ABQI        1573.98
2013-08-07 00:00:00.000 ABQI        1567.42
2013-08-06 00:00:00.000 ABQI        1579.49
2013-08-13 00:00:00.000 ACNACTR     280.3931
2013-08-12 00:00:00.000 ACNACTR     275.1943
2013-08-09 00:00:00.000 ACNACTR     268.8868
2013-08-08 00:00:00.000 ACNACTR     265.7915
2013-08-07 00:00:00.000 ACNACTR     264.8321
2013-08-13 00:00:00.000 ACNITTR     145.3845
2013-08-12 00:00:00.000 ACNITTR     144.1252
2013-08-09 00:00:00.000 ACNITTR     143.2331
2013-08-08 00:00:00.000 ACNITTR     141.4968
2013-08-07 00:00:00.000 ACNITTR     140.6079
```

How could I write a SQL query in order to subtract the indx_val by the indx_val of the previous date for all dates. I would like to find daily returns essentially. For example for `ABQI` it would be `1571.93` - `1568.55` as the return for the date `2012-08-13` and so forth. I would like for the result to have a `dt` column, `indx_nm` column, and `dly_rtn` column. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following:

```
;with cte as (
    select dt, indx_nm, indx_val,
        rn = row_number() over (partition by indx_nm order by dt desc)
    from TableName
)
select c1.dt, c1.indx_nm, c1.indx_val - c2.indx_val as dly_rtn
from cte c1
    left join cte c2 on c2.rn = c1.rn + 1 and c2.indx_nm = c1.indx_nm
order by c1.indx_nm, c1.dt desc
```

Also, if query is supposed to be run quite frequently, I would recommend having index:

```
create unique index IX_TableName_1
    on TableName (indx_nm, dt desc) include (indx_val)
```

Comment: oh, thanks! (for me it's still hard sometimes to design queries without having data in hands)

Comment: i have about 2.8  million rows of data to go through - this code has been running for a while so far - i'll let you know when its finished haha

Comment: i get weird numbers for the daily dly_rtn columns in the thousands as well as multiple values for each date

Comment: Did you tried latest? I've been correcting it (`and c2.indx_nm = c1.indx_nm` was added in the joining condition)

Comment: @euge1220, one more correction: it should be `on c2.rn = c1.rn + 1 and c2.indx_nm = c1.indx_nm` (change minus sign to plus)

Comment: yes! i just had to change `c2.rn = c1.rn - 1 ` to `c2.rn = c1.rn + 1 ` in order to corresponded the dly_rtn from say `1571.93` - `1568.55` to the date `2013-08-13`. thank you!

Comment: wow i didnt refresh the page before that, thanks again @i-one

Comment: how would i insert that data into a another table? call it tbl2 with column names dt, indx_nm, lrtn @i-one

Comment: in this case syntax is following: `;with cte as (...) insert into tbl2 (dt, indx_nm, lrtn) select ... `

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.dt,a.indx_nm ,(b.indx_val-a.indx_val)dly_rtn From table1 a join 
Table1 b on a.dt=dateadd(dd,1,b.dt) and 
a.indx_nm=b.indx_nm
```

Comment: I think you probably want to remove the `and a.indx_val=b.indx_val`.

Comment: yeah i was just going tosay that haha

Comment: this also skips over a few of the dates since its not run everyday (weekends are excluded)